# Get_by_key_name doesn't work with unicode key names of several characters

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using unicode strings for non latin characters as key names for my models.

I can create objects without problems, and the appengine admin shows key name correctly (I'm using chinese characters, and the right characters)

However, MyModel.get_by_key_name() returns None if the key_name is made of several characters.
For 1 character key name, everything works fine.

Does anyone know about that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give basic example code which demonstrates the problem you're seeing?

Comment: +1 on TC's comments. If this is a real bug, I'd love to see a reproduction case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I made some stupid encoding error when testing yesterday, which made me think the error came from the function.

The problem doesnt come from the keys. It is just an error in my algorithm that won't check for keys of 2 characters if there is no object which the 1st character as keyname.